# Is there anyway to know the status of a TEvent?

Tags: delphi

I have several threads, each with its own `TEvent`:

```
  TWorkerThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FSignal: TEvent;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
var ID: integer;
begin

  while not Terminated do begin

    Tmonitor.Enter(MainQueue);
    try
      if (MainQueue.Count > 0) then ID := MainQueue.dequeue
      else ID := 0;
    finally
      Tmonitor.exit(MainQueue);
    end;

    if (ID <> 0) then ProcessID(ID)
    else fSignal.WaitFor(INFINITE);

  end;

end;
```

Now, in the main thread I would like to retrieve the list of threads that are waiting for the signal, so those who are doing `fSignal.WaitFor(INFINITE);`

Actually I do like this in the code:

```
procedure AddIDToTheQueue(const id: integer);
begin

  Tmonitor.Enter(MainQueue);
  try

    MainQueue.Enqueue(id);

    //signal all background thread !!! this a don't like i prefer to signal only one thread who are waiting instead of signaling all the threads !!!
    for I := Low(workerThreads) to High(workerThreads) do
      workerThreads[i].Signal.SetEvent;

  finally
    Tmonitor.Exit(MainQueue);
  end;

end;
```

but it's not efficient as I signal all threads instead of signalling only the first one that is waiting for the signal. How can I do this?

Comment: Personally if would not use events at all in this situation. I would just use Yield. I think it would be both more efficient and easier to read. Then of course, you don't need to signal anything.

Comment: not understand how i can use Yield here ?

Comment: It is a method in TTHread that just passes control to the next thread.

Comment: I just saw it, but how i can use it ?

Comment: I am preparing an example by modifying your code, but I want to check it compiles first.

Comment: The strategy here is wrong.  You want to push work to your threads but then you've written the threads to pull work.  You have to choose a strategy and stick to it.  You might be better using a threadpool here (ie : TTask, etc).  What version of Delphi?

Comment: @J... I will never of the never use TTask again, it's just one of the worse buggy tools made on delphi :(

Comment: @loki That hasn't been my experience.  In any case, if you want this strategy then you're best to have a manager thread push the work to a specific thread that you know is free rather than to dump it into a pool and to tell all the threads to go racing to get it.  This is like throwing a steak into a pit of hungry dogs.  Not exactly elegant.  Each thread could have its own work queue and the manager can distribute either in sequence or to the least loaded queues.

Comment: @J... ttask is much more complex and in most of the case it's make think more bad than it's must be. As an example, take the example you just gave me! it's wrong because ttask will be by default bound to the number of CPU, if ProcessID(ID) is cpu intensive that could be ok, but if for exemple ProcessID(ID) is doing http request or any other kind of waiting you are just wasting :( and i see many other problem with ttask (including even memory leak!) but i agree with you on the idea of pool of thread ! it's what i have, now i need to find a good way to take one from the pool

Comment: @loki you can adjust the size of the threadpool used by the PPL.  If you have memory leaks, it's probably not the PPL but rather your own code that has a problem.

Comment: @loki The PPL also allows you to create your own separate threadpool (with your own parameters, size, etc) and to queue work to that pool rather than to the default pool.

Comment: @j... i know i know but sincerely i have to much bad experience with ttask to go back to it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `TEvent.WaitFor(0)` it's a bit slower... You cand make a new beautiful Event that uses Critical Section to fast check for singaled state. In this example, I also added a value to the event which can help you send a command with that signal too.

```
  TSafeCardinalEvent = class
  private
    CardinalValue: Cardinal;
    CS: TRTLCriticalSection;
    hEvent: THandle;
    function  GetEventValue: Cardinal;
    procedure SetEventValue(AValue: Cardinal);
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function  Signaled: Boolean; overload; {$IFDEF RELEASE} inline; {$ENDIF}
    function  Signaled(out Code: Cardinal): Boolean; overload;
    property  Value: Cardinal      read GetEventValue  write SetEventValue;
    property  EventHandle: THandle read hEvent;
  end;

constructor TSafeCardinalEvent.Create;
begin
 inherited Create;
 CardinalValue:= 0;
 InitializeCriticalSection(CS);
 hEvent:= CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
end;

destructor TSafeCardinalEvent.Destroy;
begin
 CloseHandle(hEvent);
 DeleteCriticalSection(CS);
 inherited Destroy;
end;

function TSafeCardinalEvent.Signaled: Boolean;
begin
 EnterCriticalSection(CS);
 Result:= CardinalValue > 0;
 LeaveCriticalSection(CS);
end;

function TSafeCardinalEvent.Signaled(out Code: Cardinal): Boolean;
begin
 EnterCriticalSection(CS);
 Code:= CardinalValue;
 Result:= CardinalValue > 0;
 LeaveCriticalSection(CS);
end;

function TSafeCardinalEvent.GetEventValue: Cardinal;
begin
 EnterCriticalSection(CS);
 Result:= CardinalValue;
 LeaveCriticalSection(CS);
end;

procedure TSafeCardinalEvent.SetEventValue(AValue: Cardinal);
begin
 EnterCriticalSection(CS);
 CardinalValue:= AValue;
 if CardinalValue = 0
  then ResetEvent(hEvent)
  else SetEvent(hEvent);
 LeaveCriticalSection(CS);
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

To directly answer your question, you can always check if an event is signalled using :

```
 if FSignal.WaitFor(0) = wrSignaled then begin
   // event is signaled
 end;
```

If you need to handle all cases, of course :

```
case FSignal.WaitFor(0) of
  wrSignaled:;
  wrTimeout:;
  wrAbandoned:;
  wrError:;
  wrIOCompletion:;
end;
```

However - this is an ideal situation to leverage the built-in threadpool by simply using tasks.

For example, all of your code can be eliminated and reduced to this :

```
procedure AddIDToTheQueue(id: integer);
var
  LTask : ITask;
begin
  LTask := TTask.Create(procedure begin ProcessID(id); end);
  LTask.Start;
end;
```

There is no sense in passing an `integer` as `const`.  Whether you pass the value or a pointer, it's the same size.  If you're not modifying it, it makes no difference.

Comment: I think this is a better approach, but I think that you should mention how to change the Execute function, just for completeness.

Comment: @Dsm You delete the Execute function and the worker thread class containing it.  This replaces all of OP's code.

Comment: I agree this could be a good approach ! if only it's didn't use TTask :( :( i spend weeks removing all ttask from my program, i m not ready to add them back :(

Answer (score 2):

I would not use events in this situation.

I would use yield.

Then Execute becomes

```
procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
var
  ID : integer;
begin
  while not Terminated do begin

    Tmonitor.Enter(MainQueue);
    try
      if (MainQueue.Count > 0) then ID := MainQueue.dequeue
      else ID := 0;
    finally
      Tmonitor.exit(MainQueue);
    end;

    if (ID <> 0) then ProcessID(ID)
    else Yield;

  end;
end;
```

and AddIDToTheQueue becomes

```
procedure AddIDToTheQueue(const id: integer);
begin

  Tmonitor.Enter(MainQueue);
  try

    MainQueue.Enqueue(id);

  finally
    Tmonitor.Exit(MainQueue);
  end;

end;
```

You are not attempting to tell your threads that a new ID is available. You are letting the first available thread handle it automatically.

Comment: hmm never think about such approach ! it's interesting !! but question does the Yield will use more CPU instead of fSignal.WaitFor(INFINITE); because in such scenario, when their is nothing to process each thread will continuously Yield each other increasing the cpu usage no ?

Comment: Yielding in a tight loop like this will saturate the CPU.  Not terribly efficient.

Comment: @J... Not sure you are right about efficiency. I cannot see it being any worse than WaitFor. I do like your threadpool idea, though. I think it is a better solution.

Comment: @Dsm Run it and see.  Each thread like this will peg a core at 100% utilization.